# How do I get the text from P tag with no closing tag

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Im using HTML Agility pack but cant get the text or p tag node with inner text when there is no closing p tag:

Sample HTML :

```
<p class=nospace>someobject
<div class="indent">
     <p class="nospace"><a class=small href="04.HTM">04</a>
     <p class="nospace"><a class=small href="05.HTM">05</a>
     <p class="nospace"><a class=small href="06.HTM">06</a>
     <p class="nospace"><a class=small href="11.HTM">11</a>
</div>
```

Problem is I want to get the "someobject" as the first object and add 04 05 06 and 11 as child objects of it. I cant get HTML Agility pack to load the p tag written as

```
    <p class="nospace" />someobject<div class="indent">...
```

Comment: It's ambiguous, because the HTML doesn't say where the `<p>` should close, should it be before the start of the next `<p>` or the end of the document?  If you know what you want, then you could write a preparser to fix the HTML by explicitly close `<p>` before a new one opens for example.

Comment: Is this even valid HTML without the closing `<p>` tag?  I know the closing is optional, but I dont think the `"someobject"` would exist _inside_ the `<p>` if it didnt have a closing tag would it?

Comment: @maccettura not sure if its valid or not...
Unfortunately I dont have access to how the source HTML is written as you can see some of hte class tags dont have "s as well I'm just trying to parse it.

I have made some headway using the following XPath not sure if there is a better way.

    //p[@class='nospace']/following-sibling::text()[1]

Comment: @Tony What is the parent to this `<p>` tag?